# How to access all text from a website, including the a tag?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all the article text from the following site:
https://www.phonearena.com/reviews/Samsung-Galaxy-S9-Plus-Review_id4494

I tried `findAll(text=True)` but it extracts lot of useless information.

So I did `findAll(text=True, recursive=False)` but it ignores text data in certain tags like ? What's the most effective way of extracting the text in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The website seems to be javascript protected. It loads the body content when requests already retrieved the http response. You need to simulate a real page request. With the python module [Selenium Webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) it would be possible.